# Notepad++ : Search for static value and replace it with value from list

Tags: regex, notepad++

## 1 File:

```
<DisplayName>**just_an_example**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**just_an_example**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**just_an_example**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**just_an_example**</DisplayName>
```

## 2 File

```
**example1**
**example2**
**example3**
**example4**
```

What do I need:

In notepad++ native search/replace dialog, search for "just_an_example" and replace it with the values from 2nd file, in sequence.

Output:

```
<DisplayName>**example1**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**example2**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**example3**</DisplayName>
<DisplayName>**example4**</DisplayName>
```

Is this possible, to search in all active files under Notepad++. Possible not using Python Script?

Comment: If you were using Sublime, you could have easily done it with [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry). Probably a similar plugin exists for Notepad++ too.

Comment: Please tell me more of your God aka Sublime. Always learning.

Comment: I've done it! Sublime... love the band, now love the editor! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that the content of file 1 is not relevant (except for the DisplayName tags).

So replace the content of file 1 by pasting all of file 2 and replace new lines by the tags. You can do that in Notepad++ by searching for `\n` and replacing it by `</DisplayName>\n<DisplayName>`. All that is left then is manually fixing the first and last line.

Comment: He also wants "to search *in all active files* under Notepad++". Greedy Pedro.

Comment: Please take into account "all" = 2 files! :D